# Visual leak detector with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, shared-ptr, visual-leak-detector

I am relatively new to shared_ptr. I'm using visual leak detector and I get errors at the end of the runtime when giving me following code as a memory leak :

```
std::shared_ptr<the_type>(new the_type(the_parameter))
```

Do i have to call something else like a deleter or even `shared_ptr::reset()` , is it visual leak detector that is telling me a false leak or it is running before the `shared_ptr` is actually being deleted?

Thanks.

note: i use vld 2.2.3, VS2012, Windows 7/8

Comment: Where is the code? In a function?

Comment: Yes, in a function. the call stack trace back to the line i posted in the question.

Comment: There cannot be any leak if that's the whole line (minus semicolon) and the ctor of `the_type` does not leak. Still, prefer `make_shared`, it is potentially more efficient (1 instead of 2 allocations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more code, it's hard to say, but one clear possibility is that you have a cycle.  Just using `std::shared_ptr` everywhere is going to lead to problems sooner or later; it's a useful tool for specific cases, but it isn't going to solve all of your problems.

Comment: It is used as a reference to the parent in a decorator pattern. In the destructor I call `parent_shared_ptr.reset()` and I call the `reset()` on the last created level of the decorator.

Comment: If the parent has a pointer to the decorator, and the decorator has a pointer to the parent, and both are `std::shared_ptr`, you have a cycle, and a leak.  (In the usual implementation, the parent doesn't know about its decorator.  But there are certainly cases where it should.  In such cases, you'll probably need a different solution than `std::shared_ptr`.)

Comment: Thanks, i changed the `shared_ptr` reference to the parent in the child to `weak_ptr` where I want the parent to own a child. It doesn't leak anymore. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with constructing a shared pointer in the way you showed. Looks like the leak detector is reporting fake leaks or you are using it in the wrong way. As a side note consider using `std::make_shared` instead of explicit `new` and shared pointer constructor - it is generally more efficient and safer.

Comment: +1 in general. I also agree that `std::make_shared` is to be preferred, with one caveat: if you're likely to keep `std::weak_ptr`s to the object long after it's been destroyed, you can save memory by *not* using `std::make_shared`.